# firebase once('value') function on database not response

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would happy for your help
I'm trying to use firebase on nodejs server.
after initial configurations I build a rest on node server that used to fetch data from firebase database

Here is the first version of the code

```
  app.get('/api/users/:id', (req,res) =>{
      const usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
      usersRef.once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot);
        res.status(200).send(snapshot.val())
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(404).send(error.message)
      })
    }))
```

I've checked the route with postman and found that I didn't received any response from that route
I've check with logs that the route received the request and I found that I must create async call to database, so, I created middleware
And here is the new version of code:

```
const asyncMiddleware = fn =>
  (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
      .catch(next);
};

app.get('/api/users/:id', asyncMiddleware(async (req,res,nex) =>{
  const usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
  await usersRef.once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot);
    res.status(200).send(snapshot.val())
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(404).send(error.message)
  })
}))
```

But the problem continue even after the changes.
So I found that the reason for the problem is because the 'once' function stack when he tried to fetch data from firebase and not return any response.

I would really like to your help here
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to do with the way you handle the asynchronous requests. Try the code below and let's see if we'll get any luck.

```
const fetchUsers = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try{
    const usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users')
    usersRef.once('value', (snapShot) => {
      resolve(snapShot)
    })
  }catch(err){
    reject(err)
  }
})

 app.get('/api/users/:id', async (req,res) =>{
    const users = await fetchUsers()
    /** 
     * clean the users response
     * and respond with data
     */

    res
      .status(200)
      .json({
        data: users //cleaned
      })

}))
```

Comment: Hi, It's didn't helps
I just Used axios & REST API of firebase

Answer (score 0):

So, After Investigate I found a solution for this problem.
I've used axios on server send request by using REST API of firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database